# maven deploy-file missing/invalid file and/or url

Tags: java, maven

When I run my command, I get the following.  Note that if I were to run the same thing from the command line ( with -D options ), it would work.  So what I am doing wrong?  -X and -e show me nothing of any value.  I am currently researching if maybe my variables are not being picked up, but the url value is clearly defined, so while that might explain the missing/invalid file error, it would not explain the missing/invalid url error.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jooq-model 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (default-cli) @ jooq-model ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.280 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-23T20:24:49-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/92M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (default-cli) on project jooq-model: The parameters 'file', 'url' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

I am using the following configuration for the maven-deploy-plugin ( tell me if you need more ):

> ```
> <build>
>     ....
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>             <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>1.4</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <id>buildnumber</id>
>                     <phase>validate</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>create</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>             <configuration>
>                 <format>{0,number}</format>
>                 <items>
>                     <item>buildNumber</item>
>                 </items>                    
>                 <doCheck>false</doCheck>
>                 <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
>                 <revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>   
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>            
>         <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>2.8.2</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <id>deploy-file</id>
>                     <phase>deploy</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>deploy-file</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
>                         <url>file://home/tonyb/.m2/repository</url>
>                         <sources>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-sources.jar</sources>
>                         <pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>            
>     </plugins>
>     <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${buildNumber}</finalName>
> </build>
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding to [The deploy:deploy-file Mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html), It told us as

> The `deploy:deploy-file` mojo is used primarily for deploying artifacts
>   to which were not built by Maven.

Especially,

> If the following required information is not specified in some way,
>   the goal will fail:
>
> - the artifact file to deploy
> - the group, artifact, version and packaging
>     of the file to deploy. These can be taken from the specified pomFile,
>     and overriden or specified using the command line. When the pomFile
>     contains a parent section, the parent's groupId can be considered if
>     the groupId is not specified further for the current project or on the
>     command line.
> - the repository information: the url to deploy to and the
>     repositoryId mapping to a server section in the settings.xml file. If
>     you don't specify a repositoryId, Maven will try to extract
>     authentication information using the id 'remote-repository'.

This means we have the built artifact e.g. `our-artifact-1.0.jar` and would like to deploy it to our repository. When execute the `deploy:deploy-file`, we have to pass those required parameters via the `-D` as the following example.

```bash
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file://C:\m2-repo \
                       -DrepositoryId=some.id \
                       -Dfile=our-artifact-1.0.jar \
```

Then if we would like to deploy our building artifact during the [Maven Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), please use `mvn deploy` instead.

Comment: Important Safety Tip: you need a remote URL if you are deploying to a remote repository; a "file" URL just goes to your local filesystem (like install does).